# Javascript error: SyntaxError: At least one digit must occur after a decimal point

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to setup an html form to perform an AJAX update when a user exits a field. I've only tried to set this up on one table cell at the moment as follows:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" onchange="updateRecord(1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F)" value="John Terry"></td>
```

However I'm getting an error as follows:

SyntaxError: At least one digit must occur after a decimal point

If I change the cell to something like this:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" onchange="updateRecord(12345)" value="John Terry"></td>
```

it works. However I need to use the longer ID string as that is the record ID required for the database update and I cannot change the format of this string.

I'm new to Javascript and AJAX so not sure what could be the issue with the longer string? There's no decimal points that I can see either.

Comment: `onchange="updateRecord(1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F)` should be `onchange="updateRecord('1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F')`. You forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to content of `1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F` having letters and `-` characters, you need to wrap it in quotes to denote it as a string literal:

```
onchange="updateRecord('1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F')"
```

Unqouted and not numeric, JavaScript is expecting a variable or other object (`null`, `false` etc). Your `12345` test works because it only contains numbers.